# C# FTP : Domain Mandatory ? , else : The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Hi I have the following code :

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + remoteFile);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            if (withDomain)
            {
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user.Normalize(), pass.Normalize(), dom.Normalize());
            }
            else
            {
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user.Normalize(), pass.Normalize());
            }

            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

I get an error only when the domain is not provided i.e in case where just username and passwords are provided i get the error.  However the same username and password are working fine with Dreamweaver or other FTP client tools.